# Transfer files to an ec2 instance

Tags: linux, http, file-transfer

I have a requirement to transfer files to an ec2 instance which is blocked by firewall. It has only **http port open at 80**.

`scp` cannot be used as it uses SSH to transfer files.
I found another option in `netcat` but i am not able to make it listen on port 80 for http requests, it defaults to TCP

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to make netcat listen for http requests? Or is this scenario impossible where we can transfer files over http considering my constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You should to have a root privileges to bind "privileged" ports(ports < 1024), so try to run it on EC2:

```
$ sudo nc -l 80 > file
```

And this on your host:

```
$ cat file | nc *ec2-instance-ip* -p 80
```

But it looks like a reinventing a wheel

Comment: Didnt work. It creates a new file , instead of copying content of the host file.